# How do I use the Django ORM to query this many-to-many example?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  author_name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
  book_name = models.CharField()

class AuthorBook(models.Model):
  author_id = models.ForeignKeyField(Author)
  book_id = models.ForeignKeyField(Book)
```

With that being said, I'm trying to emulate this query using the Django ORM (select all of the books written by a specific author, noting that Authors can have many books and Books can have many Authors):

```
SELECT book_name 
FROM authorbook, book
WHERE authorbook.author_id = 1
AND authorbook.book_id = book.id
```

I've read [this FAQ page](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/) on the Django website, but before I modify my model structure and remove AuthorBook, I was curious if I could emulate that query using the current structure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(authorbook__author_id=1)
```

to get a QuerySet of Book objects matching your author_id restriction.

The nice thing about Django is you can cook this up and play around with it in the shell.  You may also find 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships
to be useful.

Comment: webjunkie's response seems better.  Just learning Django myself.

Comment: In general, there's no reason to explicitly mention the id field in the ORM.  Assuming you have an Author instance, you'd want Book.objects.filter(authorbook__author=author).  But a ManyToManyField is the way to go, of course.

Comment: Another example lookup by author name: Book.objects.filter(authors__author_name__endswith=u' Klein') assuming you're using webjunkie's ManyToMany based schema.

Answer (score 14):

"AuthorBook" seems not correctly modeled.

You should use a `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Then you can do:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(authors__id=1)
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting ManyToManyField (that's the Django way), -1 for not knowing that that's how it's done "under the hood".

Comment: Of course do m2m relationships use intermediary tables. Still it is not correctly modeled using Django in this case. There's no point in having me making obvious that I know how it's working under the hood.